Why does my W65C51's echomode have weird bit delay?
I've recently bought a new Western Design Company 6551 IC, but after hooking it up I get a weird bit-delay while using the Echomode. When I send a character, for example 'U', it should send (startbit)01010101(stopbit).

(Every column is 100us = ~1 bit at 9600 baud)
After looking at the input signal with my scope, I can confirm that this is indeed the right signal (in yellow). The green signal is what the IC sends: the echo. In the datasheet I found that the echo is delayed by one half bit time, and I can see that this is indeed the case. But only when the signal falls (falling-edge), this is not the case with rising edge, because it directly changes the echoed signal, without the half bit delay.
Is it normal behavior for this IC to only have the half bit delay on the falling edge?
The reason I think this is weird, is because now, the spacing between the correct bits is not equal. So when the asynchronous receiver receives the signal, it sometimes read the correct bit and sometimes the wrong bit. This is the case when the red vertical line in the picture is on the green line's transition.
For clarification, the IC is connected to a USB-RS232 converter with a MAX232 in-between to convert the RS232 to UART. The MAX232 as well as the converter both work fine
datasheet: https://www.westerndesigncenter.com/wdc/documentation/w65c51n.pdf

which IC are you talking about? ... please add a link to the manufacturer's datasheet into your post ... do not write a comment

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please can you edit your question (don't add new info in comments) and add (a) a link to the 6551 datasheet, (b) details of what you have the 6551 connected to, including clocks, (c) a schematic. Thanks.

My guess is that this is normal. I assume it is intended as a debug mode to allow you to see what the IC internally has received to check it is working correctly. Presumably it resets ever bit period (hence no delay for start of bit), and then half way through the bit period where the receiver samples the data, it outputs the value it sampled. I doubt it is intended to be used a UART signal, rather just a debugging tool to allow you to see what the receiver logic is doing.

@TomCarpenter This IC's sole purpose is to buffer bits for receiving and transmitting via UART, as well as provide error checking possibilities. In my situation, I enabled the echo function on the IC, so it should echo the UART bits I send it via the TX port on the IC (Like its doing, but with the weird bit delay)

Do you have the PHI2 input pin connected to a free-running and continuous clock frequency, typically 1MHz or 2MHz? That's the arrangement the chip is designed for. Please edit your question to clarify. If you haven't got a continuous clock on there, it's probably the problem - try generating one of at least 1MHz.
